# TypeError: this.service.x is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test case for `LoginComponent.onSubmit()`. In this method the component calls `this.authService.login(email, password)` which returns a dictionary `{emailValid: boolean, passwordValid: boolean}` .

A mock version of this service is being used. I checked if `this.authService` is an instance of `MockAuthenticationService` by `console.log(this.authService)` in `LoginComponent.onSubmit()` and it is. But for some reason it can't find the login method.

I tried extending `MockAuthenticationService` from `AuthenticationService` and then override the login method which also didn't work.

I don't really know what else to try...

`LoginComponent` spec file:

```js
class MockRoutingService {
  page: string;

  constructor() { }

  route(page: string) {
    this.page = page;
  }
}

class MockAuthenticationService extends AuthenticationService {

  emailValid: boolean;
  passwordValid: boolean;

  login(email: string, password: string): { ['emailValid']: boolean, ['passwordValid']: boolean } {
    return { emailValid: this.emailValid, passwordValid: this.passwordValid};
  }
}


describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let authService: MockAuthenticationService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: RoutingService, useClass: MockRoutingService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService }
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should set emailErr to "* Your username was incorrect, please try again."', () => {
    authService.emailValid = false;
    authService.passwordValid = false;
    component.setPassword('password');
    component.setEmail('invalidemail.com');
    component.onSubmit();
    expect(component.emailErr).toBe('* Your username was incorrect, please try again.');
  });
```

`LoginComponent.onSubmit()`:

```js
onSubmit() {
    this.emailErr = '';
    this.passwordErr = '';

    const response: { ['emailValid']: boolean, ['passwordValid']: boolean } = this.authService.login(this.email, this.password);

    const self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (response.emailValid === false) {
        self.emailErr = '* Your username was incorrect, please try again.';
        return;
      } else if (response.passwordValid === false) {
        self.passwordErr = '* Your password was incorrect, please try again.';
        return;
      }
      self.routingService.route('home');
    }, 300);
  }
```

real `AuthenticationService.login()` method:

```js
login(email: string, password: string): { ['emailValid']: boolean, ['passwordValid']: boolean } {
    const responseBody = this.api.post('customers/authenticate', {email, password});
    const response: { ['emailValid']: boolean, ['passwordValid']: boolean } = {
      emailValid: null,
      passwordValid: null,
    };

    responseBody.subscribe(
      (authData: any) => {

        response.emailValid = authData.emailValid === 'true';
        response.passwordValid = authData.passwordValid === 'true';

        if (response.passwordValid && response.emailValid) {
          const currentCustomer = new Customer();
          Object.assign(currentCustomer, JSON.parse(authData.customer));
          localStorage.setItem('currentCustomer', JSON.stringify(currentCustomer));
          this.customerService.getCustomersReservations(currentCustomer).subscribe(
            (reservationData: any) => {
              currentCustomer.reservations = reservationData.reservations;
            }
          );
          this.currentCustomerSubject.next(currentCustomer);
        }
        return;
      });
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Your value is a *class*, not the instance - either use `useClass` or create an instance. Also your mocks are really *spies*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've tried that already but forgot when posting this question. I'll update the post, btw I just tried it again and still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't a spy when you actually use the real service but change the return value for a function? Or are you saying I should use spies?

Comment: Actually the MockRoutingService is a spy and the MockAuthenticationService is a *stub*, see e.g. http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb

Comment: Could you maybe fork and extend the stackblitz I created for your former question regarding the same component to recreate the error? The setup looks right. You are sure you are still getting this error? There is another problem though, that you are setting a timeout and would hence need to use ```fakeAsync``` inside your test but that should give you not the error "the method loginService.x is not defined"